# "Equality" problem in distributed computation

Tags: graphs, distributed-systems, lower-bounds

I recently started learning about distributed computation on graphs (not to be confused with parallel computation with threads).

I have seen as a side note in a few lower bound proofs, a reference that says the proof could be shorter using the "linear lower bound theorem for the Equality problem", but I couldn't find the statement or proof of this theorem.

I would like to know a few things:

- What exactly is this "Equality" problem? (how is it formulated?)
- Where can I find a proof for its lower bound? (or if the proof is short enough, I would be glad if you could add it here)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably referring to the [communication complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity) of the function $f(x,y) = 1$ if $x=y$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x \ne y$.  See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity#Example:_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000031-QINU%60%22'%7F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity#Example:_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000031-QINU%60%22%27%7F) for the formulation and a proof of the lower bound.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a theorem connecting the communication complexity of some $f$, to the complexity of a two-node graph distributed computation of the same problem?

Comment: You can formulate and prove this theorem yourself. The idea is that a protocol in the distributed setting can be converted to a protocol in the communication complexity setting.

Comment: The other direction is obvious. I will try to prove this alone, thanks!